# How to recompile with -Xlint:unchecked in Ant build task?

Tags: ant, compilation, target, build.xml

When I run the "compile" target of my Ant "build.xml" file, then I get the following message:

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

My compile target is the following:

```
  <target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,source" includeantruntime="false">
      <classpath refid="class.path" />
    </javac>
    <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,source" includeantruntime="false">
      <classpath refid="class.path" />
    </javac>
  </target>
```

What do I have to change in my build.xml file so that **-Xlint:unchecked** is done there?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Add the following element in `<javac></javac>` section:

```
<compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" />
```

Comment: Yeah! This was helpful. Thanks. The compiler claims about the use of java.util.Vector and java.util.HashSet. Since they are obsolete I have to look for equivalent types. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Benny: The uses of java.util.Vector should be replaced by java.util.List/java.list.ArrayList

Comment: @Lukasz Where should i given property in Build.gradle. I got the error in Android Studio

Comment: @NeetuShrivastava, did you find the way? If not, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In **AndroidStudio**, do this:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
```