# Httpclient-4.2 and commons httpclient in project build path

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

Can't i have `commons-httpclient.jar` and `httpclient-4.2.3 jar` as referenced libraries in my project build path ?

The ant-build fails with message

```
[javac]  Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac]  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I tried passing -Xlint:unchecked option to javac within ant, and now all my unchecked castings in the projects are getting thrown as errors and warnings. Is there a way to successfully build my project by having both jars ?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your build is failing? Or are those messages just warnings?

Comment: [javac] 15 errors
    [javac] 73 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/sreekanth/Txt2ORA/apsrtc-oprs/src/build.xml:129: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/sreekanth/Txt2ORA/apsrtc-oprs/src/apps/build.xml:30: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/sreekanth/Txt2ORA/apsrtc-oprs/src/apps/apsrtc-oprs-app/src/build.xml:247: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/sreekanth/Txt2ORA/apsrtc-oprs/src/apps/apsrtc-oprs-app/src/build.xml:71: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Usually the messages you mentioned in your question are warnings, not errors. Could you post the full log, or double check whether there aren't any **real** errors?

Comment: why it says   
[javac]` 15 errors `[javac] `73 warnings` `BUILD FAILED`

Comment: Hard to tell for me... Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597968/how-to-recompile-with-xlintunchecked-in-ant-build-task), it should take away any warnings... I suspect your build will still fail after that.

Comment: yes, in my question i already mentioned about it, -Xlint:unchecked option to javac within ant and still it fails. Thanks for your time. will try to figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

the only way i found till now is to migrate from httpclient 3.1 to httpclient 4.2. After migration the files which i migrated works fine with version 4.2 jar.

http://blog.teamextension.com/migrating-from-httpclient-3-1-to-4-0-34
 this link helped me a lot